# Removing a row in a data frame depending on the value of the previous row (R)

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am trying to clean some data after importing it as a data frame to R.
My data looks like this:

```
Event      Time
  A      10:59:36
  B      11:00:27
  A      11:01:36
  B      11:02:01
  A      11:02:15
  A      11:02:20
  B      11:02:45
```

Time is in POSIXct objects. Events are Strings.
The correct form for the data should be:
A followed by B. 
However, sometimes A is followed by A and B is followed by B. This is an error and I need to remove the latter row.
So, if two subsequent rows have the same value for 'Event' the second row has to be removed. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any possibility that the Events "A" and "B" are not equal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[!duplicated(rleid(Event))]
#     Event     Time
#1:     A 10:59:36
#2:     B 11:00:27
#3:     A 11:01:36
#4:     B 11:02:01
#5:     A 11:02:15
#6:     B 11:02:45
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Event = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", 
 "A", "B"), 
Time = c("10:59:36", "11:00:27", "11:01:36", "11:02:01", 
"11:02:15", "11:02:20", "11:02:45")), .Names = c("Event", 
"Time"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `cumsum()` and `rle()` functions to achieve what you want:

```
events <- data.frame(Event=c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B"),
                     Time=c("10:59:36", "11:00:27", "11:01:36",
                            "11:02:01", "11:02:15", "11:02:20", "11:02:45"))

rows.keep <- cumsum(rle(as.numeric(events[,1]))$lengths)
y <- c(FALSE, rows.keep[1:length(rows.keep)-1] == rows.keep[2:length(rows.keep)] - 2)
rows.keep[y] <- rows.keep[y] - 1
events <- events[rows.keep, ]

> events
  Event                Time
1     A 2016-01-25 10:59:36
2     B 2016-01-25 11:00:27
3     A 2016-01-25 11:01:36
4     B 2016-01-25 11:02:01
5     A 2016-01-25 11:02:15
6     B 2016-01-25 11:02:45
```

Comment: Wouldn't this remove the 1st occurrence of error data?

Comment: Yes, want to retain the first and remove the second

Comment: This is my output when I copy paste your exact code:                     Event     Time
1     A 10:59:36
2     B 11:00:27
3     A 11:01:36
4     B 11:02:01
6     A 11:02:20 
7     B 11:02:45                                                                                When I tried out the code, cumsum(rle(as.numeric(events[,1]))$lengths)
gives  [1] 1 2 3 4 6 7, so events[5] is removed. I want to retain events[5] and remove events [6]. Hope that makes it clear. Thanks.

Comment: @nef I updated my answer, which is working correctly now.  Not sure it matters at this point, but feel free to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` solution. The `row_number` condition is a little clumsy for my tastes, but it might nonetheless be more readable than other solutions.

```
library(dplyr)

Time <- as.POSIXct("2016-01-25 10:59:36")
set.seed(10)
dat <-
  data_frame(Event = sample(c("A", "B"), size = 15, replace = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(Time = Sys.time() + rnorm(15, 0, 999)) %>%
  arrange(Time)

dat %>%
  arrange(Time) %>%
  filter(Event != lag(Event) | row_number(Time) == 1)
# Source: local data frame [9 x 2]
# 
# Event                Time
# (chr)              (time)
# 1     B 2016-01-25 18:36:16
# 2     A 2016-01-25 18:46:30
# 3     B 2016-01-25 18:55:18
# 4     A 2016-01-25 18:58:18
# 5     B 2016-01-25 19:03:10
# 6     A 2016-01-25 19:07:20
# 7     B 2016-01-25 19:09:24
# 8     A 2016-01-25 19:14:35
# 9     B 2016-01-25 19:26:27
```

Without the `| row_number(Time) == 1)`, the first row would be omitted. Note that if there are multiple duplicated consecutive Events, only the first will be retained.